# Is there a way to get pub/sub messages into Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'd like to be able to send messages from one GCP project to many other GCP projects through pub/sub so that the downstream projects can create alerts in Stackdriver or send to Slack (whichever they choose).

Project X ---message1--> Project 1
Project X ---message2--> Project 2

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use Cloud Functions.
Consumer in Project 1 wants to use Stackdriver for surfacing alerts to their operators.

I've read through the pub/sub docs and have not been able to locate any useful info else maybe using Dataflow but not sure how to get into Stackdriver.

Is there another native GCP service that can consume from pub/sub and send into Stackdriver?

Comment: Why you can't use functions?

Comment: Please, check this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/how-to-connect-stackdriver-to-your-smart-home-server-for-error-logging-8a7a477241c2) and let me know it it suits your need.

Comment: Security team will not allow Functions until they go GA with VPSS Service Perimeter..